# How to parse JSON in Python and Bash?

Tags: python, json, bash

I need to parse via Bash and Python the JSON below. I am getting different errors.

From JSON I want to get name and ObjectID information and put it on array. But don't know how to do this.

Example of JSON :

```
  {
    "aliases": [],
    "localizations": {},
    "name": "Super DX-Ball",
    "popularity": 0,
    "objectID": "7781",
    "_highlightResult": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Super DX-<em>Ba</em>ll",
        "matchLevel": "full",
        "fullyHighlighted": false,
        "matchedWords": [
          "ba"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aliases": [],
    "localizations": {},
    "name": "Katekyo Hitman Reborn! DS Flame Rumble X - Mirai Chou-Bakuhatsu!!",
    "popularity": 0,
    "objectID": "77522",
    "_highlightResult": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Katekyo Hitman Reborn! DS Flame Rumble X - Mirai Chou-<em>Ba</em>kuhatsu!!",
        "matchLevel": "full",
        "fullyHighlighted": false,
        "matchedWords": [
          "ba"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aliases": [],
    "localizations": {},
    "name": "Bagitman",
    "popularity": 0,
    "objectID": "7663",
    "_highlightResult": {
      "name": {
        "value": "<em>Ba</em>gitman",
        "matchLevel": "full",
        "fullyHighlighted": false,
        "matchedWords": [
          "ba"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aliases": [],
    "localizations": {},
    "name": "Virtual Bart",
    "popularity": 0,
    "objectID": "7616",
    "_highlightResult": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Virtual <em>Ba</em>rt",
        "matchLevel": "full",
        "fullyHighlighted": false,
        "matchedWords": [
          "ba"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting error due that few independends jsons. Here is an example :

```
cat /tmp/out | jq ".name"
"Fortnite"
parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 35, column 4
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? Show the code and the corresponding error message.

Comment: The error message means that the JSON is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input JSON looks like an array but lacks brackets. Try to add them:

```
$ (echo '['; cat /tmp/out; echo ']') | jq 'map({ name, objectID })'
[
  {
    "name": "Super DX-Ball",
    "objectID": "7781"
  },
  {
    "name": "Katekyo Hitman Reborn! DS Flame Rumble X - Mirai Chou-Bakuhatsu!!",
    "objectID": "77522"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bagitman",
    "objectID": "7663"
  },
  {
    "name": "Virtual Bart",
    "objectID": "7616"
  }
]
```